# Writing a loop by fixing one index and comparing to every other index of that same array

Tags: python, loops

For an array, i want to fix one index value and compare it to every other index value. e.g. Fix x[0] and if any of x[1], x[2], ..., x[n] are larger than x[0] return its index value. Then fix x[1], return any x[0], x[2], ..., x[n] that are larger than x[1] and so on.... so for each i, it should return an array. What is this called, is there a special loop for this, i cannot figure how to code it?

```
x = np.array([1,4,9,4,5,5,2])
n = len(x) 
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-1):
        if x[j] > x[i]:
            print(x[i:j])
```

This returns

```
[1 4]
[1 4 9]
[1 4 9 4]
[1 4 9 4 5]
[4]
[4 9 4]
[4 9 4 5]
[]
[4]
[4 5]
[]
[]].
```

But since x[0] = 1, then every value in x is bigger than this so it should return [1,2,3,4,5,6].

For x[1] = 4, it should only return [2,4,5] since these are all larger.

Comment: Where do `3` and `6` come from in the sample output for `x[0] = 1`?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem These are the 3rd and 6th indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code:

```
x = [1,4,9,4,5,5,2]
for i in range(len(x)):
    print([j for j in range(len(x)) if x[j]>x[i]])
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 4, 5]
[]
[2, 4, 5]
[2]
[2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

if you must use numpy:

code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,4,9,4,5,5,2])
for i in range(len(x)):
    print([j for j in range(len(x)) if x[j]>x[i]])
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 4, 5]
[]
[2, 4, 5]
[2]
[2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

if you want to use it as a function:

code:

```
def foo(dic):
    return [[j for j in range(len(dic)) if dic[j]>dic[i]] for i in range(len(dic))]

print(foo([1,4,9,4,5,5,2]))
```

result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 4, 5], [], [2, 4, 5], [2], [2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: out of interest how can i write this as a function so it returns each j for a random array? I tried to write `def algo(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        A = ([j for j in range(len(x)) if x[j]>x[i]])
    return A` but could not get the same output? (Sorry new to python)

Answer (score 1):

you can use np.where()

```py
x = np.array([1,4,9,4,5,5,2])
for val in x:
    print(np.where(x > val))
```

results:

```
(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int64),)
(array([2, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([2, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)
(array([2], dtype=int64),)
(array([2], dtype=int64),)
(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)
```